# Add /api/v1/ url scheme to rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I'm planning a web app that is exposed primarily through a client application through an API. I've worked with rails before so am going to use this to create the back-end.

Whilst planning the API, I've added in a layer to the url scheme that is as follows:

http://websitename.com/api/v1/...

What is the best way for me to add this to my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try to [grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape). It's a little gem that will help you to design and code this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used Grape as mentioned above but you can always go with a scope in your routes file.

```
scope '/api' do
    match v1/something_here => controller_name#method_name, :as=>'desired_name'
end
```

OR

```
scope '/api/v1'
```

if you need it.

OR

```
scope :module => 'api', :as => 'api' do
    scope '/v1' do

    end
end
```